# .NET Regex dot character matches carriage return?

Tags: .net, regex

Every single flavor of regex I have ever used has always had the "." character match everything but a new line (\r or \n)... unless, of course, you enable the single-line flag.

So when I tried the following C# code I was shocked:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(".");
if (rgx.Match("\r\n").Success)
  MessageBox.Show("There is something rotten in the state of Redmond!");
```

It showed the message. Just to make sure I wasn't going insane, I tried the following JavaScript code:

```
if (/./.test("\r\n"))
  alert("Something's wrong with JavaScript too.");
```

The JavaScript didn't show the message, meaning it's working exactly as it should.

Apparently, the "." character in .NET is matching the "\r" character. I checked the  [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) to see if the mention anything about it:

> Wildcard: Matches any single character
>   except \n.

Wow... since when does a Regex flavor *ever* have the dot match a carriage return? You would think .NET would behave like all the rest of the Regex flavors... especially because it's in a Windows environment which uses "\r\n" as line delimiters.

Is there any flag/setting I can enable to make it work as it does in other Regex flavors? Are there any alternative solutions which don't involve replacing all `.` characters with `[^\r\n]`?

Comment: You might think that using RegexOptions.ECMAScript would help, but it still fails.

Comment: It's 2021, and the problem is still unsolved.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ran into this same issue when writing Regex Hero.  It is a little bizarre.  I blogged about the issue [here](http://regexhero.net/blog/2009/05/intricacies-of-whitespace.html).  And that led to me adding a feature to the tester to enable/disable CRLFs.  Anyway, for some reason Microsoft chose to use \n (line feeds) to mark line endings.

(UPDATE) The reason must be related to this:

> Microsoft .NET Framework regular
>   expressions incorporate the most
>   popular features of other regular
>   expression implementations such as
>   those in Perl and awk. **Designed to be
>   compatible with Perl 5 regular
>   expressions**, .NET Framework regular
>   expressions include features not yet
>   seen in other implementations, such as
>   right-to-left matching and on-the-fly
>   compilation.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx

And as Igor noted, Perl has the same behavior.

Now, the Singleline and Multiline [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) change behavior based around dots and line feeds.  You can enable the Singleline RegexOption so that the dot matches line feeds.  And you can enable the Multiline RegexOption so that ^ and $ mark the beginning and end of every line (denoted by line feeds).  But you can't change the inherent behavior of the dot (.) operator to match everything except for \r\n.

Comment: @Steve Wortham: "include features not yet seen in other implementations, such as right-to-left matching and **on-the-fly compilation**" -- he-he, Perl regexes are precompiled by default and were compiled on-the-fly long before .NET came to existence

Comment: @Igor: What they're talking about is using the `Compiled` option to create a separate class in CLR (CLI?) bytecode just for that regex.  It can even be saved in its own DLL.  The result is much faster than a simple Regex object, but the overhead involved in compiling it tends to offset that advantage if the regex isn't used a lot.

Comment: Too bad Microsoft wasn't as generous when they decided on which new line character to use in Windows. If they would have chosen to be compatible with Unix back then, then we wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think the point here is that the dot is supposed to match anything that's not a line separator, and `\r` is a line separator.  Perl gets away with recognizing only `\n` because it is (as others have pointed out) rooted in the Unix world, and because it's the inspiration for the regex flavors found in most other languages.

(But I note that in Perl 6 regexes (or Rules, to use their formal name), `/\n/` matches anything that's recognized by Unicode as a line separator, including both characters of a `\r\n` sequence.)

.NET was born in the Unicode era; it should recognize *all* Unicode-endorsed line separators, including `\r` (older Mac style) and `\r\n` (which is used by some network protocols as well as Windows).  Consider this example in Java:

```
String s = "fee\nfie\r\nfoe\rfum";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)^.+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find())
{
  System.out.println(m.group().length());
}
```

result:

```
3
3
3
3
```

`.`, `^` and `$` all work correctly with all three line separators.  Now try it in C#:

```
string s = "fee\nfie\r\nfoe\rfum";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?m)^.+$");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Value.Length);
}
```

result:

```
3
4
7
```

Does that look right to anyone else?  Here we have the regex flavor built into Microsoft's .NET framework, and it doesn't even handle the Windows-standard line separator correctly.  And it completely disregards a lone `\r`, as it does the other Unicode line separators.  .NET came out several years after Java, and its Unicode support is at least as good, so why did they choose to stick on this point?

Answer (score 3):

Except in SingleLine mode, `.` will match every character except `\n`.
As you've noticed, it does match `\r`.

I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions have a practical (as opposed to theoretical) origin in the Unix environment, where LF is the line terminator then it seems completely appropriate for . to match everything except LF.

It's a single character match so matching CRLF would be too much to ask and matching CR or LF might cause problems with migrating regex's cross-platform. I think using \s would be a better approach for white-space matching and will match both CR and LF.

Comment: And deleted it again, for no apparent reason?

Comment: My deleted answer is not a solution.  I tried it, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: That's because singleline makes . match everything.  The OP wants it to be equivalent to [^\r\n]

Comment: +1 to Lazarus.  It looks like grep and grep -E behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think that "there is something rotten in the state of Redmond!", at least your scenario is not a proof of it. But I *do think* that this behavior is not a bug but rather a feature. Why? Just because Perl regexes features the same behaviour (I just checked it) and I believe that PHP's PCREs (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) behave the same way too. And MS just made their Regex methods behave the same way as de-facto classic Perl ones. And now my question is: "what's wrong in the JS kingdom?" :)