# Regex.Replace removes '\r' character in "\r\n"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Here is a simple example

```
string text = "parameter=120\r\n";
int newValue = 250;

text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=parameter\s*=).*", newValue.ToString());
```

`text` will be `"parameter=250\n"` after replacement. Replace() method removes '\r'. Does it uses unix-style for line feed by default? Adding `\b` to my regex `(?<=parameter\s*=).*\b` solves the problem, but I suppose there should be a better way to parse lines with windows-style line feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282181/net-regex-dot-character-matches-carriage-return). In short, the period (`.`) matches every character except `\n` in pretty much all regex implementations. Nothing to do with Replace in particular - you told it to remove any number of `.`, and that will slurp up `\r` as well.

Can't test now, but you might be able to rewrite it as `(?<=parameter\s*=)[^\r\n]*` to explicitly state which characters you want disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

`.` by default doesn't match `\n`..If you want it to match you have to use single line mode..

```
(?s)(?<=parameter\s*=).*
 ^
```

`(?s)` would toggle the single line mode

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string text = "parameter=120\r\n";
int newValue = 250;

text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(parameter\s*=).*\r\n", "${1}" + newValue.ToString() + "\n");
```

Final value of `text`:

> parameter=250\n

Match carriage return and newline explicitly. Will only match lines ending in `\r\n`.

Comment: Your example will not work on .Net (it looks like php or perl) but the regex with `\r\n` works fine
`text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=parameter\s*=).*(?=\r\n)", newValue.ToString());
`

Comment: @Max have you tried it? Works great for me under .net 4.0 and .net 4.5. I assume the jarring syntax is the ${1} - it inserts a backreference from the pattern match into the replacement string.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. The result is `"$1250\n"`. Yes, ${1} confused me :).

Comment: @Max I made an edit that changed "$1" to "${1}" because that gave the results you quote. "${1}" is working great for me. What version of .net are you using?