# Regex- match every thing that is in bracket including newline

Tags: regex, vb.net

script file content is

```
//{input: x(width),y(height);
//output: z(area);}

function(x,y)
z=x*y
```

I have to read only these lines. What will be the regular expression for data that is in curly braces

```
//{input: x(width),y(height);
//output: z(area);}
```

I tried the following

```
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(scriptpath)
    ' Dim textToParse As String
    Dim scriptText As String
    scriptText = sr.ReadToEnd

    Dim extractCommentRegex As New Regex("\/\/\{(.*?)\}")
    Dim textToParse As Match = extractCommentRegex.Match(scriptText)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
^\/\/\{.*\}
```

with /m option to make dot match newlines.

Hi, sorry haven't been writing vb for quite a while so did not make the answer clear enough. I've created a console project to test following code:

```
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("d:\script1.txt")
    ' Dim textToParse As String
    Dim scriptText As String
    scriptText = sr.ReadToEnd

    Dim match = Regex.Match(scriptText, "^\/\/\{.*\}", RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)

    Console.WriteLine(match.Success)

    Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("d:\output.txt")

    sw.Write(match.Value)

    sw.Flush()
    sw.Close()
    Console.ReadLine()
```

And I'll get following for output.txt.

```
//{input: x(width),y(height);
//output: z(area);}
```

I think you need to provide RegexOptions If you have Windows format LF for the input file. for detail of the issue please see this thread:

[.NET Regex dot character matches carriage return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282181/net-regex-dot-character-matches-carriage-return)